# Serverless framework won't start with dynamodb local

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

## EDIT: As answered below by Carlos, this was a bug with *serverless-dynamodb-local* version 0.2.23 (version as of this edit is 0.2.35). It has now been resolved and if you are experiencing a similar issue you should update your dependencies.

I had a working dev environment of an AWS Lambda function developed on the Serverless framework, using DynamoDB (plugins: serverless-offline, serverless-dynamodb-local . After deleting node_modules and reinstalling, I have lost the ability to start the development server, which I used to do with `serverless offline start`

`serverless offline` works properly, but if I try to run dynamodb locally it throws the following error:

```
Reference Error ----------------------------------------

  options is not defined

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

ReferenceError: options is not defined
    at BbPromise.resolve.then (/Users/pablo/Documents/myProject/node_modules/serverless-dynamodb-local/index.js:164:21)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (/Users/pablo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:236:22)
    at PluginManager.run (/Users/pablo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:255:17)
    at variables.populateService.then (/Users/pablo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:99:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
From previous event:
    at Serverless.run (/Users/pablo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:86:74)
    at serverless.init.then (/Users/pablo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:39:50)

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Forums:        forum.serverless.com
     Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           6.10.3
     Serverless Version:     1.19.0
```

Oddly enough, if I go to localhost:8000/shell, the dynamodb shell is running.

has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Same here, but latest version (0.2.23) was published yesterday. I reverted to 0.2.22 and it works fine, so it's probably a bug or a new requirement not documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns it was an issue, registered and solved here: https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/120

You can download the version 0.2.24 by typing `npm i serverless-dynamodb-local@0.2.24 --save-dev` if you are using it as a development dependency.

Comment: Hey @Pablo, if this solved your issue please mark it as 'solved' :)

Answer (score 1):

First, add Serverless Offline to your project:

```
npm install serverless-offline --save-dev
```

Then inside your project's `serverless.ym`l file add following entry to the plugins section: `serverless-offline`. If there is no plugin section you will need to add it to the file.

It should look something like this:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

You can check wether you have successfully installed the plugin by running the serverless command line:

```
serverless
```

the console should display Offline as one of the plugins now available in your Serverless project.

then In your project root run:

```
serverless offline start or sls offline start.
```

Reference [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline)

Comment: Hi Mayur. Thank you for your answer, but this particular issue was a glitch caused by an error in a specific version that has since been patched.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a very subtle detail. I had `stage` set as `local`. So, I had to put the following line in the `custom` section of `serverless.yml` file:

```
custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - local
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the below and it resolved the issue for me

```
sls dynamodb install --localPath ./bin
```

Reference https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/210

Answer (score -1):

serverless-dynamodb-local 0.2.35 worked for me

```
yarn remove serverless-dynamodb-local
yarn add serverless-dynamodb-local@0.2.35
sls dynamodb install
```

Answer (score -2):

run command

```
sls dynamodb install --stage dev
```

Comment: Only for T2Bs:-
1. Download OpenJDK on your system  first - sudo apt install default-jdk